# MariaDB audit log empty host

Tags: mysql, mariadb, audit

I'm running MariaDB 10.0.23 with the audit plugin logging CONNECT type.  The audit log is showing a failed connect with error 1042.  Does the host field not show the IP address when a host cannot be resolved?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Log Entry

```
20160220 00:47:26,XXXXHOSTXXXXX,,,642901,0,FAILED_CONNECT,,,1042
20160220 00:47:26,XXXXHOSTXXXXX,,,642901,0,DISCONNECT,,,0
```

Comment: Show us the log

Comment: @Iain Updated with log entries.